# Почему убунту на виртуал боксе лагает?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Установил убунту на виртуал бокс. Мои характеристики: i38100, 8bg озу, видеокарта gtx1650GAMING X(4GB). В виртуал боксе выделил 128мб видеопямати, 3 процессора, 5 гб озу, включил ускорение 3d, в разделе паравиртуализация выбрал HYPER-V. Вроде бы все ок, но ubuntu тормозит, это видно даже при скроллинге, это жестко режет глаз. Еще и когда открываю список приложений, картинка при появлении приложений словно искажается на секунду. Читал, что убунту тормозит потому что на ней нет драйверов видеокарты и что надо установить гостевые дополнения. Я установил их через: устройства, подключить гостевые дополнения. Читал, что это может не помочь (мне не помогло) и скачал через консоль. Все равно не помогает. Что мне делать? Гостевые дополнения я поставил , но лаги остались.

Comment: А при чём тут гиперв? Ты же с вбоксом работаешь.

Comment: Гуест тулз поставил?